# I can not build correct rest url with related models

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have a Rest URL to load all user cards:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/client/cards")
public class CardsController
```

I have a Rest URL to load all transactions:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/client/transactions")
public class TransactionsController
```

One card has multiple transactions. Now I need get all transactions by card. How can I build currect URL?

I can add a method to `CardsController`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{guid}/page/{page}")
  public TransactionsResponse getCardTransactions(@PathVariable String guid, @PathVariable int page)
```

or I can add method to `TransactionsController`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{cardGuid}/page/{page}")
  public TransactionsResponse getTransactionsByCardGuid(@PathVariable String cardGuid, @PathVariable int page)
```

but I do not like to have both ways because the full URL will look like:

`/api/client/cards/{guid}/page/{page}` //nothing is said about the transaction

or

```
/api/client/transactions/{cardGuid}/page/{page}//cardGuid not at the right place
```

I feel that it is correct to place it inside `TransactionsController` but how can I correctly build the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no "correct" way of doing REST URLs, it just needs to be readable enough in most cases.

You can refer to this [link](https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/) for guidelines.

You can use something like this for your URL.

```java
@RequestMapping("/api/client/{cardId}/transactions")
public class getTransactionsByCardId(@PathVariable("cardId") Long cardId)
```